# django-allauth Custom Sociallogin Signup Form with keyOrder

Tags: python, django, forms, django-allauth

Using Django 1.7 and found out how to change the keyOrder, but the problem is that Sociallogin doesn't have password1 and password2 fields, so this won't work:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fields_keyOrder = ['username', 'email','age', 'sex', 'password1', 'password2', 'captcha']
        if (self.fields.has_key('keyOrder')):
            self.fields.keyOrder = fields_keyOrder
        else:
            self.fields = OrderedDict((k, self.fields[k]) for k in fields_keyOrder)
```

I tried to create another Form for Sociallogins that does not have password1 in the keyOrder but there is an error when trying to access the form:

```
class SocialSignupForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SocialSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fields_keyOrder = ['username', 'email','age', 'sex']
        if (self.fields.has_key('keyOrder')):
            self.fields.keyOrder = fields_keyOrder
        else:
            self.fields = OrderedDict((k, self.fields[k]) for k in fields_keyOrder)
```

*Error :*

**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sociallogin'

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working. No need for a second Signup Form, so remove this from settings.py: **SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS={'signup': 'yourapp.forms.SocialSignupForm'}**

The solution is to add ***if hasattr(self, 'sociallogin')***

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, 'sociallogin'):
            fields_keyOrder = ['username', 'email', 'listening_device', 'age', 'sex']
        else:
            fields_keyOrder = ['username', 'email', 'listening_device', 'age', 'sex', 'password1', 'password2', 'captcha']
        if (self.fields.has_key('keyOrder')):
            self.fields.keyOrder = fields_keyOrder
        else:
            self.fields = OrderedDict((k, self.fields[k]) for k in fields_keyOrder)
```